# C++ bitwise operations

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I am operating on individual bits of two integers, (i am using g++ for compilation on Ubuntu machine).

In some intermediate step, I have the bit representations as

```
q = 11000000000000000000000000000000
q_1 = 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Now I want to check whether unit's places of q and q_1 are both same or not. so, I am checking `(*q)&1==q_1` in the if condition, and its working fine.

But whenever I want to check that unit's place of q is 0 and that of q_1 is 1, I thought I should do `((*q)&1==0) && (q_1==1)`, but it is not working out as expected. For debugging, I `cout` ed the values of `((*q)&1==0)` and `(q_1==1)` individually and they got printed as `1`. However, the value of `((*q)&1==0) && (q_1==1)` got printed as 0. Why?

**EDIT : ** In the function, q was passed by reference, so I am using *q to get the value..

Comment: About your EDIT: you mean, passed as pointer? If it was passed as *reference*, then you wouldn't use the `*`.

Comment: This is such a classic bug that a minimum of research would give you the cause: bitwise & has lower operator precedence than ==. As a rule of thumb: if you don't know all of the operator precedence rules in detail, then use a parenthesis.

Comment: sorry for that, I already used a lot of parenthesis around `(*q)` because of not knowing the precedence, got confused because both the operands of `&` were `1` and still I was getting `0` as output...

Comment: @hyde, yes, passed as pointer...the function definition says void `func(int *q,int*m)`

Comment: Always use parentheses around bit operators.  Their precedence is either not what you would naturally expect (`&`, `^`, `|` are on the wrong side of comparison operators, probably because they were confounded with logical operators), or unclear (`<<`, `>>`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C and C++, the bitwise `&` operator actually has lower precedence than the equivalence operator `==`.  You'll need to wrap your bitwise operators in parentheses.

So:

```
((*q)&1==0) && (q_1==1)
```

should be:

```
(((*q)&1)==0) && (q_1==1)
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Also `(*q&1)==0 && q_1==1` would be just enough.