# bit representation of unsigned int zero

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, unsigned

I ran into a behavior which I didn't expect using bitwise operations on unsigned ints. I'll cut right to my example.

```
unsigned int a = 0;
unsigned int b = 0;
std::printf("a & b: %u\n", a & b);
std::printf("a == b: %i\n", a == b);
std::printf("a & b == a: %i\n", a & b == a);
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
a & b: 0
a == b: 1
a & b == a: 0
```

The last line is what confuses me. Shouldn't `a & b == a` evaluate to `true`, since `a & b == (unsigned int)0` and `a == (unsigned int)0`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ bitwise operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14645473/c-bitwise-operations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting this behavior because you didn't realize `==` comes before `&` in the [C operator precedence table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm).  In fact, a good compiler will warn you straight away about your code:

```
t.cpp:10:35: warning: & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]
std::printf("a & b == a: %i\n", a & b == a);
                                  ^~~~~~~~
t.cpp:10:35: note: place parentheses around the '==' expression to silence this warning
std::printf("a & b == a: %i\n", a & b == a);
                                  ^
                                    (     )
t.cpp:10:35: note: place parentheses around the & expression to evaluate it first
std::printf("a & b == a: %i\n", a & b == a);
                                  ^
                                (    )
```

Make sure your warnings are turned on, like `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Answer (score 5):

You should write:

```
(a & b) == a
```

Now you'll get 1 since `a & b` [will be evaluated first](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

`(a & b) = 0`, `0 == 0` is 1.

In your case, `a & b == a` is evaluated as `a & (b == a)`, `b == a` is 1, and `a & 1` is 0.

Answer (score 5):

Due to [`==`'s precedence over `&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `a & b == a` gets evaluated as `a & (b == a)` (and not as `(a & b) == a` as you appear to have expected).